# How to extend an existing key in a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, key, extend

I want to extend an existing key in a dict with an information.
The key `'abc'` should then be completed with a `'d'` so that the result is `'abcd'`.
Something like this:

```
info1='abc'
info2='d'
DataDict[info1 '%i' %info2] = DataDict.pop(info1)
```

but it does not work...

Comment: This page contains some approaches for this, with code examples: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-ways-to-change-keys-in-dictionary/

Answer (score 1):

For a dict, this is a contradiction: a different key is *entirely* a different entry.
You can, perhaps, make it a little more readable for your algorithm, but you still have to create a new key and remove the old one.

```
old_key = "abc"
extension = 'd'
my_dict[old_key + extension] = my_dict[old_key]
del my_dict[old_key]
```

Depending on your use case, you may want to make a new copy of the old value.

Ah ... I see tha tyou are comfortable with `pop`.  In that case, you were quite close with your (edited) solution:

```
my_dict[old_key + extension] = my_dict.pop(old_key)
```